# If we put a spin-1 particle inside the 3D potential well, What will be the density of states for the system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, density-of-states

What will the density of states be if the particle inside the 3d potential well is a spin 1 particle?

$$\psi(x,y,z)_{n_x,n_y,n_z}= \left(\frac{2}{L}\right)^{3/2} \sin\left(\frac{n_x\pi x}{L}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n_y\pi y}{L}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n_z\pi z}{L}\right)$$

I am aware of how the density of states is calculated for an electron but if the electron were to be replaced with a spin 1 particle, then how would the density of the states change?

Comment: Three times the density of a spinless particle...i.e. 3/2 times  the one of electrons.

Comment: Provide the Hamiltonian, please. How do the spin degrees of freedom coupled to the real space x,y,z coordinates?